# Is there something like React.Fragment in Vue?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, fragment

In React I can do something like this:

```
// parent component
export default (){
  return (
     <div>
       <div>1</div>
       <ChildComponent />
       <div>5</div>
     </div>
  );
}

// child component
export default (){
  return (
     <React.Fragment>
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
       <div>4</div>
     </React.Fragment>
  );
};

// compiled html tags in browser .
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

But in Vue , when I've done the same thing , something went difference .

```
// parent component
<template>
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <child-component />
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import childComponent from 'path/to/childComponent';
    export default {
      components: { childComponent }
    }
</script>
-------------------------------------------------------------
// child component
<template>
    <div id='have_to_write_in_vue'>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    <div>
</template>

// compiled html tags in browser .
<div>1</div>
<div id='have_to_write_in_vue'>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
<div>5</div>
```

The difference is that 'DIV' tags are not at same level in Vue .
How can I handle this ?

I'm asking this is because of something went wrong when useless nesting appearing.

Comment: There's something similar, please check [this github](https://github.com/y-nk/vue-fragment#readme). This is one of probably several modules for this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### **Vue 2**

Package [Vue-fragment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragment) facilitates root-less components for vue 2.

### **Vue 3**

Vue 3 have official support for multi-root node components (fragments) https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html

Answer (score 15):

The lack of a first party Fragment component in Vue drives me nuts!

I had looked at the the `vue-fragment` npm package, but it made me nervous at how much they were doing and felt there had to be a better way.

I came up with something extremely lightweight... It works because functional components are allowed to return multiple root nodes.

This doesn't work 100% like Reacts, however. In React, you can actually use a `React.Fragment` as the root node in your app, for example. This seems to only work in Vue when you're already within a component (ie: it can't be the root node of your base component).

```js
const Fragment = {
  functional: true,
  render: (h, ctx) => ctx.children
}
```

to use it...

```
<Fragment>
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
</Fragment>
```

Super useful...

```
{someCondition && (
  <Fragment>
    <div>yay i can use multiple nodes</div>
    <div>:)</div>
  </Fragment>
)}

<div>
  Some inline text {condition ? (
    <Fragment>now I can use <strong>html</strong> and {variables}</Fragment>
  ) : (
    <Fragment>So many possibilities</Fragment>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: this looks good. could you explain how you implemented this Fragment component?

Comment: it is a functional component that uses ctx.children. Vue functional components allow multiple root nodes. The code for the functional component is up within the answer `const Fragment = {...}`

Comment: okay thanks. but sadly i got an error which says "[Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node." on Vue v2.6.11

Comment: did you add `functional: true` ?

Comment: @Roi even with `functional: true`

Comment: Hello! Even me it says [Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node.
Using "vue": "2.6.10"

Comment: Well, this is weird!  I tried this method a week or 2 ago, and it didn't work.  Then, I tried it today, and it worked like a charm!  I wish I could remember what I tried doing back then, but either way, I can definitely say that it works.  That being said, I'll try to remember this post to keep people updated on what might have been the issue if I run into that bug again. 

Comment: The issue is just where and how you use it... it can't be used as the root node for your component, only as a child in jsx

Comment: It could be that that's what I tried to do, but I don't remember.  You're probably right though.

Comment: When I do this (found the rest on the vue site) `export default Vue.component('Fragment', {  functional: true, render: (h, ctx) => ctx.children})` then my child component are not accessible through `$refs` and it's an empty object. I use `Fragment` at the root level under `template` to suppress the warning `Unknown html tag Fragment`

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, Vue.js v3 now supports fragments out of the box: [Fragments (Vue.js documentation)](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html)

Comment: Vue has always supported nesting `<template>`s and they work just as `<React.fragment>`s. It's not something added in v3. The only difference between v2 and v3 is that in v2 the root `<template>` of a component had to be limited at only 1 child. Now that limitation is gone, at the cost of not having an `$el` anymore. Now if you want any DOM element in template you have to use a `$ref`.

Comment: True, thanks for the update. Here I meant multi-root frgments, which are new in v3. In React, you would use `<React.Fragment>` (or `<></>`) to overcome the single-root limitation, which is what the OP asked for, I assume.

Answer (score 8):

### Vue v3

<strike>*This is a simple adaptation of @Roi's answer for Vue v3.*</strike>

As @dakujem mentions, Vue v3 supports multi-root components out-of-the-box. However it does not support deeply nested fragments.

**UPDATE**: You can nest `<template>`!

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <template>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Of course you can. You can [nest SLOTs too](https://dev.to/dakujem/nested-slots-with-vue-js-1efd) (v2 and v3 both).

Comment: `<template>` doesn't work "standalone". It needs a v-if or v-for. And `<template v-if="true">` works as well.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: create a component `Frag.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```

---

As mentioned in other answers you can nest `template`s, with a caveat:

You can do `v-if`

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li>
      first
    </li>
    <template v-if="true">
      <li>
        second
      </li>
      <li>
        third
      </li>
    </template>
    <li>
      fourth
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

producing:

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

or `v-for`

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li>
      first
    </li>
    <template v-for="i in list">
      <li>
        second {{i}}
      </li>
      <li>
        third {{i}}
      </li>
    </template>
    <li>
      fourth
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

producing:

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second 0</li>
  <li>third 0</li>
  <li>second 1</li>
  <li>third 1</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

However, without `v-for` or `v-if`:

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li>
      first
    </li>
    <template>
      <li>
        second
      </li>
      <li>
        third
      </li>
    </template>
    <li>
      fourth
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

it produces

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

You can work around it by always using `v-if="true` but it's a little less than ideal.

Having said that, because slots in templates spread all the passed children into the default slot, you can create a very simple component:

```html
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```

That's it. Call it `Frag.vue`, import it wherever you need it. You can use it with `v-if`, `v-for`, or with neither.

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li>
      first
    </li>
    <Frag v-if="true">
      <li>
        second (v-if)
      </li>
      <li>
        third (v-if)
      </li>
    </Frag>
    <Frag v-for="i in list">
      <li>
        second {{i}} (v-for)
      </li>
      <li>
        third {{i}} (v-for)
      </li>
    </Frag>
    <Frag>
      <li>
        second (nothing)
      </li>
      <li>
        third (nothing)
      </li>
    </Frag>
    <li>
      fourth
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

producing:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    first
  </li>
  <li>
    second (v-if)
  </li>
  <li>
    third (v-if)
  </li>
  <li>
    second 0 (v-for)
  </li>
  <li>
    third 0 (v-for)
  </li>
  <li>
    second 1 (v-for)
  </li>
  <li>
    third 1 (v-for)
  </li>
  <li>
    second (nothing)
  </li>
  <li>
    third (nothing)
  </li>
  <li>
    fourth
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those whom use Vue 3 + JSX/TSX you can do either of the following:

```js
<>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
</>
```

*or*

```js
import { Fragment } from 'vue';

<Fragment>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
</Fragment>
```

Note: I utilise the `@vue/babel-plugin-jsx` to support JSX/TSX.

Comment: `Module '"../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'Fragment'`

Answer (score 0):

Found this awesome directive and is battle-tested! https://github.com/privatenumber/vue-frag

```html
<template>
    <div v-frag> <!-- This element will be unwrapped -->

        <div v-for="i in 10">
            {{ i }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import frag from 'vue-frag';

export default {
    directives: {
        frag
    }
};
</script>
```

From the README:

How is this different from vue-fragment?

They are both designed to do the same thing. However, vue-fragment is a component and vue-frag is a directive. I made vue-frag when I saw vue-fragment didn't have any tests to ensure correct behavior, had a lot of unattended issues, and didn't seem actively maintained. In terms of size, they are both small but vue-frag is slightly smaller (993B vs 798B).

Answer (score -1):

Just use a nested `template` tag to wrap multiple child Vue components.

```
<template>
  <template>
    <div class="my-first-child"></div>
    <div class="my-second-child"></div>
    <div class="my-third-child"></div>
  </template>
</template>
```

This will result in

```html
<div class="my-first-child"></div>
<div class="my-second-child"></div>
<div class="my-third-child"></div>
```